# What's the purpose of 'read more' dividers on non-paywalled pages?

Tags: interaction-design

Some non-paywalled news websites started recently adding 'see more' dividers to their articles on mobile versions of their sites.

This made sense on sites likes the Wall Street Journal, where you have to be a paying subscriber to continue reading, but what about free-to-access articles? What's the purpose of adding them there?

We can't say that it's for analytics (how many people read beyond this threshold) since we already have more precise tech for this that doesn't require the user to click on a button.

Some notable examples are: qz.com, techcrunch.com and nytimes.com.

Comment: <cynical>Used to drive more page views and more advertising dollars</cynical>

Answer (score 2):

My theory is that it's a way to improve their bounce rate. If an organization is obsessed with metrics, they start to think of up ways to lower their bounce rate. In this case, when users click on the Read More link triggers an event in Google Analytics and doesn't count against the bounce rate. Just a theory, I don't have anything that confirms that.

Comment: Having worked at a newspaper publisher where execs were more and more obsessed with engagement metrics, I have to agree. The percent of read more clicks to page views, will also be used to see what content "works" and what doesn't too.